# Working with multiple input variables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, syntax

So I'm very new to coding and I'm learning python so I decided I'd try to make a loan calculator. I made it so when the user inputs their principle, interest rate, and years required to pay the loan in full, it will output their annual payment, their monthly payment, and their total payment for the loan. I made this and it worked. I decided to take it a step further and make it so that after this, if the user inputs their annual income, it will compare their monthly income to their monthly payment and tell them if they need to refinance or not.

Here's the program I made:

```
principle = float(input("Principle: ")) #principle = the amount of dollars borrowed
rate = float(input("Rate: ")) #rate = the interest rate that is charged each year on unpaid principle
years = float(input("Years: ")) #years = the number of years required to repay the loan in full

payment = ((1 + rate)**years * principle * rate)/((1 + rate)**years - 1)

#lines 7-10 print the annual, monthly, and total payments made respectively
print("Annual payment: ${:,.2f}".format(payment))
print("Monthly payment: ${:,.2f}".format(payment/12))
print("Total paid for the life of the loan: ${:,.2f}".format(payment*years))

principle = float(input("Principle: ")) #principle = the amount of dollars borrowed
rate = float(input("Rate: ")) #rate = the interest rate that is charged each year on unpaid principle
years = float(input("Years: ")) #years = the number of years required to repay the loan in full

payment = ((1 + rate)**years * principle * rate)/((1 + rate)**years - 1)

annualinc = float(input("Annual income: ")) #annualinc = the annual income

#to check if the user needs to refinance or not by comparing their monthly 
income to their monthly payment
if (annualinc / 12) <= (payment / 12) and rate > .05:
    print("You should refinance")
elif (annualinc / 12) <= (payment / 12):
    print("You should seek financial counseling")
else:
    print("If you make all your payments, your loan will be paid on time.")
```

The only way I could get the if statement to work is by having the user re-input every variable between the print statements and the if statement. Whenever I put the variable `annualinc = float(input("Annual income: ")` at the beginning of the program before the print statements or between the print statements and if statement it would break the line after it with a syntax error. Why did I have to ask for all the variables again and why could I not just ask for the variable annualinc by itself? And why does it not work when I put it with the first group of variables?

edit: I fixed it so I don't have to put in all the variables again! I was missing a parenthesis at the end of the line and I've been copy and pasting the line when I moved it around so the error traveled with it. Sorry for such a rookie mistake and thank you!

Comment: please share the version(s) that "didn't work", along with the error message you got

Comment: A Syntax error means you made a mistake in the *way* you typed a statement - you mis-typed something or forgot something or included something that the interpreter couldn't understand. A common mistake is forgetting a closing parenthesis or a comma. It probably had nothing to do with the sequence of your statements.

Comment: Your code gives me a syntax error because the line `income to their monthly payment` is not commented, but it clearly belongs to a comment. Could be here the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this suit you?

```
principle = float(input("Principle: ")) #principle = the amount of dollars borrowed
rate = float(input("Rate: ")) #rate = the interest rate that is charged each year on unpaid principle
years = float(input("Years: ")) #years = the number of years required to repay the loan in full

payment = ((1 + rate)**years * principle * rate)/((1 + rate)**years - 1)

#lines 7-10 print the annual, monthly, and total payments made respectively
print("Annual payment: ${:,.2f}".format(payment))
print("Monthly payment: ${:,.2f}".format(payment/12))
print("Total paid for the life of the loan: ${:,.2f}".format(payment*years))

annualinc = float(input("Annual income: ")) #annualinc = the annual income

#to check if the user needs to refinance or not by comparing their monthly income to their monthly payment
if (annualinc / 12) <= (payment / 12) and rate > .05:
    print("You should refinance")
elif (annualinc / 12) <= (payment / 12):
    print("You should seek financial counseling")
else:
    print("If you make all your payments, your loan will be paid on time.")
```

I just eliminated the redundant parts and it works on my machine!

Comment: Thank you! That's actually what I did initially but I thought it didn't work because I forgot a parenthesis at the end of the line for the annualinc variable, since I copy and pasted the line when I tried moving it around to fix it, the error traveled with it. I really appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @Rachel No problem! We all make simple mistakes from time to time XD